# how can i reshape these images as a 2d images tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

I am currently working with rgb images loaded as tensors and i would like to reshape them to be 2d tensors to implement deep neural networks on them

the shape which I am currently working on is :

```
images.shape

torch.Size([32, 3, 244, 244])
```

I dont know how to deal with the last two fields and also how to flatten the 3 channels of colors

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is too hazy and it's unclear what you want to achieve with these images. Do they come with labels? If not, do you want to use an unsupervised method such as an autoencoder? Looking at the shape of your `images` tensor:

```
torch.Size([32, 3, 244, 244])
```

This means that there are 32 color (RGB) images in this tensor. If your definition of 2D means converting them to grayscale images, then you can use the `torchvision` library.

```
images = [torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()(img) for img in images]
images = [torchvision.transforms.Grayscale()(img) for img in images]
```

And to convert the PIL grayscale images back to torch tensor, use:

```
images = [torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()(img) for img in images]
images = torch.stack(images).to(device)
```

Now, the shape of `images` would be `[32, 244, 244]`

Flattening the much high resolution image at the very first layer is not a recommended idea. So, that's why you see in the computer vision literature that folks apply few convolution layers in the beginning of the model architecture so as to *downsample* them to smaller size (resolution) feature descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something simple like this

```
image = image.view(image.shape[0], -1)
```

That will flatten the image to have two dimensions your batch size and the product of your three other dimensions.

Comment: this will create an image with shape like torch.Size([32, 178608]), is it convience to build a neural network with an image with this size, I dont know as I am still a beginner. Like how many hidden layers needed to get the output to predict as I have two outputs in the final layer

Comment: No I assumed you were going to put it through a few CNN's first. You usually only flatten it after you have made it smaller through a few CNN layers. You can use grayscale like in the second answer if you don't want you models to be rgb.